# jquery tabs not working with jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

im building a small web application using jquery mobile and i have used the tabs from jquery UI.. But for some reason the tabs doesnt seem to be working

You can see a demo [here](http://vidznet.com/debug/)

There are no errors on the console view either.

Below is my code for the tabs

```
 $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#overview_page', function(){ 
  
  $('#linechart').tabs();
    
  });
```

also when i view the page the charts overlap and look very messy But when resize the page it works fine...

Can some please let me know what might causing these problems?

Comment: I am seeing that you used `$( '#linechart' )` , but there is no such id in that page element.

Comment: @BhargavBhandari Thanks...i have no idea how did that id change.. Thanks any way :)

Comment: You should try accordian for mobile devices @LiveEn

Comment: why you are loading jquery-ui in the body? maybe this will help you: [Jquery UI dialog not working along side JQuery Mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41102490/jquery-ui-dialog-not-working-along-side-jquery-mobile)/41163312#41163312